# Why Kubuntu,ubuntu 14.04 and similiars dissapears the initial logo when starts the so

Tags: kubuntu

Hello I'm have this dumb question that are that when i installed kubuntu 14.04 in the star of the S.O the so show the logo of kubuntu (like all the so)but when i restarted the pc this dissapear only show a text and after show a console and start the so.

Really this not a serious problem xD but i want to know why happens this xD.
Thanks

this is the logo in the start of kubuntu:

[image]

now only show a text "kubuntu 14.04" and later a type of cosole or something.

thanks xD

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that It is linked with the parameter of your boot loader (grub by default).

In the configuration file or at boot time edit the grub lines and look for a line like:

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-40-generic root=UUID=0x......-xxx ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

if *quiet* and *splash* are missing, you will get a console start.

If you use a "safe boot" variant, it is probably the case also.

Comment: Hey Where is the config file for edit this? xP

Comment: Not too sure: I got lost with the grub changes lately: press e at boot after selecting your boot sequence (if you have dual boot), otherwise have a look to /boot/grub/grub.conf (but this should not be the place to update your boot config)

Comment: Well I enter in the boot (I have dual boot) I see it the config for the ubuntu option, Well say exactly the same line that you writed in your coment.What means?

Comment: If your grub lines are correct, then  my guess is wrong. 
The problem must be somewhere else. 
You may try to read the log files to identify a meaningful error message (/var/log/messages or ~/.xsession-errors)

Comment: .xsession-errors said:                                      Script para none iniciada en run_im.
Script para auto iniciada en run_im.
Script para default iniciada en run_im.